# How to Connect Kinect 2 for Xbox One with PC

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, openkinect, xbox-one

I have an Xbox One with Kinect 2. I want to know if I can connect it to my PC, and if so, how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no official way to connect the XBOX One Kinect with a PC. A [hack](http://www.engadget.com/2014/07/18/hackers-make-xbox-ones-kinect-work-on-a-pc/) might be available one day, but I would not recommend going that way.

Buy a "Kinect for Windows V2 Sensor" - that includes the license and SDK to develop your own applications with the Kinect V2.

Comment: Microsoft has now provided an official way to connect Xbox One's Kinect 2 to a PC via an official adapter called Kinect Adapter for Windows: [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/purchase/default.aspx#tab=2)

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft Finally came up with a sane solution to Xbox Kinect One problem
Check this out
http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msca/en_CA/pdp/Kinect-Adapter-for-Windows/productID.308878000

Comment: this link is outdated

Comment: I believe this is the updated link: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/kinect

Answer (score 4):

You can un-officially connect the XBone Kinect to a PC.

Although you'll invalidate your warranty on the Kinect you should still be able to use it with the XBone afterwards.

Not sure if its a great idea for your project though - you'll still need a Windows 8 PC with the right USB 3.0 controller for it to work and you are at risk of non-windows Kinect SKUs being blocked/nerfed in future.

But basically:

- Disconnect the USB lead from the Kinect
- Take the Kinect apart
- Solder a 12v power supply to the USB 3.0 powered-B side pins where the connector joins the PCB (these are extra pins in addition to the standard USB 3.0 spec for "special" device power input/output)
- Connect the Kinect to the PC with a standard USB 3.0 B cable

A picture of where to solder the 0v/12v wires is [here](http://www.tatsch-it.de/kinect-2-usb-3-modification/).
I connected them to a barrel connector to fit a spare laptop PSU.

This works for me with Windows 8.1 and the MS KinectSDK public preview 1407.

Comment: This seems way too risky, i think i should order the kinect for windows. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

To connect Kinect 2 (Xbox One) to your PC, you need a 12 V power supply and this cable:
[image: Cable]
<sub>(source: [diskdoctors.com](http://www.diskdoctors.com/ArticleImages/The%20Seagate%20Backup%20Plus%201tb%20Disconnects%20After%20Using%20USB%203.jpg))</sub>

Using information from this picture:

[image: Cable assembly]

Kinect 2 cables:
[image: Kinect Cable]

Change standard Kinect cable with a new cable USB 3.0 A, other cables (grey and brown is 12 V power).

Comment: Did you do it & tested ?

Answer (score 0):

I connected the 12 V DC , as it must be in some photos;I used a Renesas USB 3.0 PCI-EXPRESS card and a 3m cable;and Kinect XBOX ONE was not detected by windows;I cut and re -made the long USB3 cable to 1m cable; and again nothing detected by PC.
It looks that a POWER ENABLE  signal STRAP(CONNECTION) must be made somehow(in the kinect 2)

The "distinct" hackers forgot to explain that signal (how to).
I didn't have the time to analyze the good images of the original USB3 HUB with the industrial USB3 B male connectors uploaded on web(by the way some photos disappeared meanwhile) This industrial USB3 cable of Microsoft has USB3 standard-5 pins, USB2 standard-4 pins  + another additional 4 pins (of course one is ground and one is 12 V, and at least one not documented.

Fortunately I have about 4 projects to work till connecting the sensor and Microsoft did
something interesting. It manufactured and sells the adapter for the sensor separately.
A bit expensive, at 50$ but however we speak about one power adapter, a USB3.0 HUB and a USB 3.0 cable. ( the price had to be better at 30$) , even so it is not killing price.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/purchase/default.aspx#tab=2
and it looks already available for purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure hardware matches standards if you are using a PCIe USB 3 adapter - your motherboard will probably have to support PCIe 2.0 ([PCI Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express)).